# Forked server crashed and can't bind

Tags: c, fork, port, bind

I have an forked server which is listening specific port and using 'SO_REUSEADDR' socket option. here is the problems what i got. crahing the server is another issue, but,

1. once server crashed, forked child process still running. not a problems so far.
2. also server port binded when it run. this is problems.
3. can't run again until child process died.

any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you kill it?

Comment: Close the listen socket in the child process, right after the fork.

Comment: once server crashed - I think, it is a your real problem.